# Still having to re bind? jquery actions even though using .on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bind

i have many different form / button actions on one page.

I have a file called e.g. "pageActions.js"

I have this included in the page at the bottom of the body tag as so:

```
<script src="/js/pageActions.js"></script>
```

For all of the button actions i am using .on to bind them to the page:

```
    $(document).on('click','.commentson',function(){   
        $("#hideshow").attr("class", "commentsoff");
        $("#hideshow").prop('value', 'Turn Comments On');
    });
```

My impression was that no matter what i did on the page in terms of ajax calls, this button would always work.

However, i have an ajax call on the page and in the response i use .load() on a container.

After this .load(), the above button click wont work. If after the .load(), in the ajax call i put the .on click method again, then it works fine.

This wouldnt be a problem, but i have multiple ajax calls, and also multiple buttons / forms  which WILL end up messy.

Does the .on NOT work and the elements NOT stay bound to the page if they are in the element that has the .load() function called on it?

Or is there another way to make the buttons always work?

Or... is there a way to "re implement" the pageActions.js in the ajax call?

Many thanks!

Comment: you never, ever want to delegate from the document. Put that binding into a function, and call that function both on page load and any necessary success function AJAX may affect it with. and please chain your `#hideshow` assignments.

Comment: what do you mean by "in the response i use .load() on a container" ?

Comment: The function way may solve my issues :) and the load is like so: $('#container').load('#container');

Comment: I am not sure if this will work `$('#container').load('#container');`. Is it not supposed to have a URL?

Comment: The .load() was to show change to dynamic data. @PlantTheldea the function way worked wonders! You have solved a massive set back for me! And its such a simple solution! Never heard of chaining, am looking into it now! Thanks!